Fill surface of circle with solid or transparent colour in 3dtools
I'm trying to figure out how to fill the surface of a circle plotted with 3dtools with a solid or transparent colour. For example, in the MWE below, I would like to colour the surface of the green circle with a green colour surrounded by a line of green as well. The examples I saw for tikz, 3d-plot, and tikz-3dplot-circleofsphere don't seem to work in 3dtools. Is someone able to show me ropes on how to go about doing this?
Here's the MWE:
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{3dtools,calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[3d/install view={phi=0,theta=-20,psi=135},declare function={R=3;}] 

\path  (0,0,0) coordinate (O) 
\draw[3d/screen coords] (O) circle[radius=R]; 
\path 
%horizon
pic[fill,green,fill/ .style={opacity=0.05}]{3d/circle on sphere={R=R,C={(O)},n={(0,1,0)}}}
%meridian
pic[fill,red]{3d/circle on sphere={R=R,C={(O)},n={(1,0,0)}}}
%Celestial equator
pic[fill,red]{3d/circle on sphere={R=R,C={(O)},n={(0,{sin(60)},{cos(60})}}}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

